# How to set transparent node on mesh

Tags: materials

I have a simple mesh (face) and i want to add image (eye) on it. I tried

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i connect to alpha i get black result. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: The Transparent shader shouldn't have the image color channel going to it. The image color needs to go to a shader type that will actually draw it.

Comment: @hekete you mean this way. https://imgur.com/a/q5irU0z still not getting the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you set up an image texture to use alpha transparency:

(Replace Diffuse shader with any shader that produces the output you want)
[image]

You will need to mix in your wood texture either before or after this. Do something like:

(Just use the alpha channel to mix between your wood and image)
[image]

Comment: getting black image result https://imgur.com/a/LsSve4U

Comment: Your image texture needs to feed into something that can draw it. The yellow color dot needs to join with another yellow color dot.

Comment: @atek I've added a second picture to illustrate. In your pictures you don't have the color output connected to something that will actually draw it, which is why it's a black area.

Comment: I think im a on edge to finish. The background wood texture not seen just its giving the color not look as if its on the wood. https://imgur.com/a/3QkqKzF

Comment: @atek Can you disconnect the image color output from your Wood 01 shader? It should not be connected to it and may be the cause.

Comment: Perfect Thanks..